# IdentityServer3 - how to use Access_token

Tags: identityserver3

I have a access_token in IdentityServer3.
What do I do with this access_token?

I tried to follow [this](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch16.html#_accessing_protected_resources) document, and 
[image]

my attempt:
[image]

So after this, Im trying to use this access_token to get the claim.
In order to gain access via my client details, I still have the Authorization in the Headers, and in the body I am trying to follow the document I showed above and  set a Authorization with bearer : access_token

[image]
I believe I am way out, but I am trying and getting nowhere

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want user details - try hitting the `userinfo endpoint` instead of calling the token endpoint twice.

```
GET http://localhost:35373/identity/connect/userinfo
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

[Link to IdSrv3 docs](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/userinfo.html)